# Too Many Weights in Multinomial logistic regression and the code is running for hours

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, nnet

I have a DF(train_market) having 8523 rows and 12 Columns as shown [image]

And I'm Doing multinomial logistic regression model to get the ITem_Outlet_Sales on the test_data.
but the code to run the model is running from hours together

```
 model <- nnet(Item_Outlet_Sales~.,train_market,family="multinomial",size = 5574900,softmax=TRUE)
```

I tried others two shown below but still its running for hours, what changes should i do to get it done

```
 model <- multinom(Item_Outlet_Sales~.,train_market,family="multinomial")
 model <- nnet(Item_Outlet_Sales~.,train_market,family="multinomial",size = 5574900,softmax=TRUE)
```

And i got the error for the 2nd Code as

```
Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : 
 too many (5574828) weights
```

so kept size =5574900 in 3rd and tried,Which dint help.

Comment: At first glance, your first line is missing a comma before "size". Also I haven't seen the syntax ```Item_Outlet_Sales~.``` before, with a period. Seems like you're just missing your independent variables in the regression. In general, too, it's a good idea to specify ```data = train_market``` explicitly, because multinom isn't a commonly used function.

Comment: That was a typo near size,and  `Item_Outlet_Sales~.` takes all the columns in the data frame instead of using `variable1+variable2`

Comment: @rsoren When i specify `data = train_market` explicitly also same thing

Comment: What question are you trying to answer? You should only be including the variables you need to answer that question. By dumping everything into the model, you're going to have multicollinearity issues and run out of degrees of freedom. As of now, you're asking the model to give a unique estimate for every item/outlet combination, which, by definition, is going to have only 1 data point each. Finally, multinomial logistic regression is only for when you have a nominal outcome. It looks like your dependent variable of interest is continuous, so you're better off using classical linear regression

Comment: Yes, Thanks I should go with classical Linear regression.`lm` is working now

Answer (score 5):

There is the argument `MaxNWts` in the `nnet` package in general for controlling the maximum number of weights. Hence, setting `MaxNWts` to a sufficiently large integer (for example, `MaxNWts =10000000`) should do the job:

```
model <- nnet(Item_Outlet_Sales~.,train_market,family="multinomial",size = 5574900,softmax=TRUE,MaxNWts =10000000)
```